# Private variable shares between objects

Tags: java

I have class that looks like

```
public class Sender {
    private LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(this.toString());
    private final ArrayList<CSAMessage> sentHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    public void send(final CSAMessage message) {
        doSend(message);
        sentHistory.add(message);
    }

    private void doSend(CSAMessage message) {
        //do send stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is - when two instances of Sender class are called in same time, they share private sentHistory field. In logs it looks like

> Sender1  send(...) was called, message was added to own sendHistory list
>   Sender2 send(...) was called, message was added to Sender1 sendHistory list

How is that posiible? I'm shure that Sender1 and Sender2 are different instances, they called from different threads, but call was made in same time.

I already tried to make variable 'volatile' - no result
This block gives no result too

```
private final ArrayList<CSAMessage> sentHistory;

{
    sentHistory = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Only synchronizing via class helps

```
public void send(final CSAMessage message) {
    synchronized (Sender.class) {
        doSend(message);
        sentHistory.add(message);
    }
}
```

But this will be performance bottleneck - many Senders must be able to work in same time. And why should i do so? Different instances must use it's own variables!
There are also log variable that has been declared same way, but logging variable not shared between objects, every Sender write logs from it's own name.

Comment: You're right. That must not happen and it's really unlikely that it happens the way you describe. Such a bug in Java would affect all programs. It must be a mistake on your side debugging it.

Comment: Well, what logging-API are you using? Best guess: `Logging.getLogger(this.toString())` maps to the same Logger because `toString()` returns the same value for both instances

Comment: It looks that the problem is with your logs, not with the actual array list - there is no way two instances of `Sender` can share that list (unless you set it like this using reflection api).

Comment: Try to write a [mcve] - from the bits of code you describe, your problem is impossible to reproduce.

Comment: How the log determines to who the message has been added ? (own/senderX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking the variable `final` and initializing it the way you did

```
private final ArrayList<CSAMessage> sentHistory = new ArrayList<>();
//      ^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

makes it absolutely impossible for multiple instances to share the same `ArrayList`.

What remains possible, however, is for multiple `ArrayList`s to share the same instances of `CSAMessage`. In cases when shared `CSAMessage`s are mutable, it is possible to create an illusion of sharing. For example, if `CSAMessage` has a link back to `Sender` which is set as part of a `send` call, making a change concurrently may present the message as if it were sent through a wrong sender.

Comment: The problem is messages were send with correct Sender and went to correct receiver, without any problems, but THEN they was add to ArrayList of another instance. And no - CSAMessage have no links to Sender through which it was sent.

Comment: @Asprelis Are messages shared? Are messages mutable?

Comment: Messages are mutable. But both instances of Sender received same Message object, which was modified on the fly from different threads, you're right. list.hashcode() is hashcode of all elements in list. Same elements - same hashcode of lists, that's why i decided that lists was shared.